# I am trying to improve the performance speed of my cross-correlation algorithm. What things can I do to make my C code run faster?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, cross-correlation

I created a cross-correlation algorithm, and I am trying to maximize its performance by reducing the time it takes for it to run. First of all, I reduced the number of function calls within the "crossCorrelationV2" function. Second, I created several macros at the top of the program for constants. Third, I reduced the number of loops that are inside the "crossCorrelationV2" function. The code that you see is the most recent code that I have.

Are there any other methods I can use to try and reduce the processing time of my code?

Let's assume that I am only focused on the functions "crossCorrelationV2" and "createAnalyzingWave".

I would be glad for any advice, whether in general about programming or pertaining to those two specific functions; I am a beginner programmer. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRAYSIZE 4096
#define PULSESNUMBER 16
#define DATAFREQ 1300

// Print the contents of the array onto the console.
void printArray(double array[], int size){
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < size; k++){
        printf("%lf ", array[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// Creates analyzing square wave. This square wave has unity (1) magnitude.
// The number of high values in each period is determined by high values = (analyzingT/2) / time increment
void createAnalyzingWave(double analyzingFreq, double wave[]){
    int highValues = (1 / analyzingFreq) * 0.5 / ((PULSESNUMBER * (1 / DATAFREQ) / ARRAYSIZE));
    int counter = 0;
    int p;

    for(p = 1; p <= ARRAYSIZE; p++){
        if ((counter % 2) == 0){
            wave[p - 1] = 1;
        } else{
            wave[p - 1] = 0;
        }
        if (p % highValues == 0){
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

// Creates data square wave (for testing purposes, for the real implementation actual ADC data will be used). This
// square wave has unity magnitude.
// The number of high values in each period is determined by high values = array size / (2 * number of pulses)
void createDataWave(double wave[]){
    int highValues = ARRAYSIZE / (2 * PULSESNUMBER);
    int counter = 0;
    int p;
    for(p = 0; p < ARRAYSIZE; p++){
        if ((counter % 2) == 0){
            wave[p] = 1;
        } else{
            wave[p] = 0;
        }
        if ((p + 1) % highValues == 0){
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

// Finds the average of all the values inside an array
double arrayAverage(double array[], int size){
    int i;
    double sum = 0;
    // Same thing as for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    for(i = size; i--; ){
        sum = array[i] + sum;
    }
    return sum / size;
}
// Cross-Correlation algorithm
double crossCorrelationV2(double dataWave[], double analyzingWave[]){
    int bigArraySize = (2 * ARRAYSIZE) - 1;
    // Expand analyzing array into array of size 2arraySize-1
    int lastArrayIndex = ARRAYSIZE - 1;
    int lastBigArrayIndex = 2 * ARRAYSIZE - 2; //bigArraySize - 1; //2 * arraySize - 2;

    double bigAnalyzingArray[bigArraySize];

    int i;
    int b;
    // Set first few elements of the array equal to analyzingWave
    // Set remainder of big analyzing array to 0
    for(i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++){
        bigAnalyzingArray[i] = analyzingWave[i];
        bigAnalyzingArray[i + ARRAYSIZE] = 0;
    }
    double maxCorrelationValue = 0;
    double currentCorrelationValue;


    // "Beginning" of correlation algorithm proper
    for(i = 0; i < bigArraySize; i++){

        currentCorrelationValue = 0;
        for(b = lastBigArrayIndex; b > 0; b--){

            if (b >= lastArrayIndex){
                currentCorrelationValue = dataWave[b - lastBigArrayIndex / 2] * bigAnalyzingArray[b] + currentCorrelationValue;
            }

            bigAnalyzingArray[b] = bigAnalyzingArray[b - 1];
        }

        bigAnalyzingArray[0] = 0;
        if (currentCorrelationValue > maxCorrelationValue){
            maxCorrelationValue = currentCorrelationValue;
        }
    }

    return maxCorrelationValue;
}
int main(){
    int samplesNumber = 25;
    double analyzingFreq = 1300;


    double analyzingWave[ARRAYSIZE];
    double dataWave[ARRAYSIZE];

    createAnalyzingWave(analyzingFreq, analyzingWave);
    //createDataWave(arraySize, pulsesNumber, dataWave);

    double maximumCorrelationArray[samplesNumber];

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < samplesNumber; i++){
        createDataWave(dataWave);
        maximumCorrelationArray[i] = crossCorrelationV2(dataWave, analyzingWave);
    }
    printf("Average of the array values: %lf\n", arrayAverage(maximumCorrelationArray, samplesNumber));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _What things can I do to make my C code run faster?_...  If it is working, non-buggy code, post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: **Have you measured?** Without measuring, can't talk about optimization. Try compiling with optimization options. For many constructs, the compiler can do a much better job at optimization than a human.

Comment: You're dividing by zero here: `int highValues = (1 / analyzingFreq) * 0.5 / ((PULSESNUMBER * (1 / DATAFREQ) / ARRAYSIZE));`.

Comment: Compile with optimization. `gcc -O3` is only 3 seconds while just plain `gcc` takes 14.

Comment: `if (p % highValues == 0){
            counter++;
        }` calculation can be done outside the loop in O(1) time.

Comment: Some low hanging fruit is to start using const correctness, like you should be doing for the sake of readability anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The first point is that you are explicitly shifting the analizingData array, this way you are required twice as much memory and moving the items is about 50% of your time. In a test here using `crossCorrelationV2` takes 4.1 seconds, with the implementation `crossCorrelationV3` it runs in ~2.0 seconds.

The next thing is that you are spending time multiplying by zero on the padded array, removing that, and also removing the padding, and simplifying the indices we end with `crossCorrelationV4` that makes the program to run in ~1.0 second.

```c
// Cross-Correlation algorithm
double crossCorrelationV3(double dataWave[], double analyzingWave[]){
    int bigArraySize = (2 * ARRAYSIZE) - 1;
    // Expand analyzing array into array of size 2arraySize-1
    int lastArrayIndex = ARRAYSIZE - 1;
    int lastBigArrayIndex = 2 * ARRAYSIZE - 2; //bigArraySize - 1; //2 * arraySize - 2;

    double bigAnalyzingArray[bigArraySize];

    int i;
    int b;
    // Set first few elements of the array equal to analyzingWave
    // Set remainder of big analyzing array to 0
    for(i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++){
        bigAnalyzingArray[i] = analyzingWave[i];
        bigAnalyzingArray[i + ARRAYSIZE] = 0;
    }
    double maxCorrelationValue = 0;
    double currentCorrelationValue;


    // "Beginning" of correlation algorithm proper
    for(i = 0; i < bigArraySize; i++){

        currentCorrelationValue = 0;

        // Instead of checking if b >= lastArrayIndex inside the loop I use it as
        // a stopping condition.
        for(b = lastBigArrayIndex; b >= lastArrayIndex; b--){
            // instead of shifting bitAnalizing[b] = bigAnalyzingArray[b-1] every iteration
            // I simply use bigAnalizingArray[b-i]
            currentCorrelationValue = dataWave[b - lastBigArrayIndex / 2] * bigAnalyzingArray[b - i] + currentCorrelationValue;
        }

        bigAnalyzingArray[0] = 0;
        if (currentCorrelationValue > maxCorrelationValue){
            maxCorrelationValue = currentCorrelationValue;
        }
    }

    return maxCorrelationValue;
}
```

```c
// Cross-Correlation algorithm
double crossCorrelationV4(double dataWave[], double analyzingWave[]){
    int bigArraySize = (2 * ARRAYSIZE) - 1;
    // Expand analyzing array into array of size 2arraySize-1
    int lastArrayIndex = ARRAYSIZE - 1;
    int lastBigArrayIndex = 2 * ARRAYSIZE - 2; //bigArraySize - 1; //2 * arraySize - 2;

    // I will not allocate the bigAnalizingArray here
    // double bigAnalyzingArray[bigArraySize];

    int i;
    int b;
    // I will not copy the analizingWave to bigAnalyzingArray
    // for(i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++){
    //     bigAnalyzingArray[i] = analyzingWave[i];
    //     bigAnalyzingArray[i + ARRAYSIZE] = 0;
    // }
    double maxCorrelationValue = 0;
    double currentCorrelationValue;


    // Compute the correlation by symmetric paris 
    // the idea here is to simplify the indices of the inner loops since
    // they are computed more times.
    for(i = 0; i < lastArrayIndex; i++){

        currentCorrelationValue = 0;

        for(b = lastArrayIndex - i; b >= 0; b--){
            // instead of shifting bitAnalizing[b] = bigAnalyzingArray[b-1] every iteration
            // I simply use bigAnalizingArray[b-i]
            currentCorrelationValue += dataWave[b] * analyzingWave[b + i];
        }
        
        if (currentCorrelationValue > maxCorrelationValue){
            maxCorrelationValue = currentCorrelationValue;
        }
        if(i != 0){
            currentCorrelationValue = 0;
            // Correlate shifting to the other side
            for(b = lastArrayIndex - i; b >= 0; b--){
                // instead of shifting bitAnalizing[b] = bigAnalyzingArray[b-1] every iteration
                // I simply use bigAnalizingArray[b-i]
                currentCorrelationValue += dataWave[b + i] * analyzingWave[b];
            }
            
            if (currentCorrelationValue > maxCorrelationValue){
                maxCorrelationValue = currentCorrelationValue;
            }
        }
        
    }

    return maxCorrelationValue;
}
```

If you want more optimization you can unroll some iterations of the loop and enable some compiler optimizations like vector extension.